# Error compiling Nana example (nana v1.1.2/1.1.3) with gcc 4.8.4/clang3.4

Tags: c++, linux, user-interface, gcc4.8, nana

I tried the latest nana (1.1.2/1.1.3) downloaded from Github. The library compiles fine. When I try to compile and link any sample program, with linux (gcc 4.8.4, clang 3.4) I get the following errors:

```
enter In file included from /installs/nana/include/nana/gui/wvl.hpp:20:
In file included from /installs/nana/include/nana/gui/widgets/form.hpp:16:
In file included from /installs/nana/include/nana/gui/widgets/widget.hpp:17:
/installs/nana/include/nana/internationalization.hpp:69:7: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::wstringstream' (aka 'basic_stringstream<wchar_t>') and 'nana::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>'))
                    ss << nana::string(nana::charset(arg));
                    ~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8 /system_error:186:5: note: candidate function [with _CharT = wchar_t, _Traits = std::char_traits<wchar_t>] not viable: no known conversion from 'nana::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') to 'const std::error_code' for 2nd argument
operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os, const error_code& __e)
^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/ostream:108:7: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'nana::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') to '__ostream_type &(*)(__ostream_type &)' for 1st argument
  operator<<(__ostream_type& (*__pf)(__ostream_type&))
  ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/ostream:117:7: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'nana::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') to '__ios_type &(*)(__ios_type &)' for 1st argument
  operator<<(__ios_type& (*__pf)(__ios_type&))
  ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/ostream:127:7: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'nana::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') to 'std::ios_base &(*)(std::ios_base &)' for 1st argument
  operator<<(ios_base& (*__pf) (ios_base&))
  ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/ostream:166:7: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'nana::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') to 'long' for 1st argument
  operator<<(long __n)
  ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/ostream:170:7: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'nana::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') to 'unsigned long' for 1st argument
  operator<<(unsigned long __n)
  ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/ostream:174:7: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'nana::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') to 'bool' for 1st argument
  operator<<(bool __n)here
```

CMAKE:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(nana_ui)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11
    -DSTD_CODECVT_NOT_SUPPORTED")
SET(NANA_BASE "/installs/nana")
include_directories(${NANA_BASE}/include
        /usr/include/freetype2)
link_directories(${NANA_BASE}/lib)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${NANA_BASE}/lib/libnana.a
        X11 pthread rt Xft png asound)
```

Example cpp:

```
#include <nana/gui.hpp>
#include <nana/gui/widgets/label.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace nana;
    form fm;
    label lb(fm, fm.size());
    lb.caption(L"Hello, World");
    fm.show();
    exec();
}
```

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: May be duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/q/33543674/1034749 ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding #define NANA_UNICODE in config.hpp, then recompile the library and examples