# Cannot use nana library

Tags: c++11, nana

I try to use Nana library with Code::Block IDE. I made all settings like [here](http://nanapro.org/en-us/help/instl_lib_doc.htm)

and add -std=C++11 flag and Boost include path but it's print next error on building:

> nana/include/nana/paint/graphics.hpp|143|error: ‘unsigned int nana::paint::graphics::bidi_string(const nana::point&, const char*, std::size_t)’ cannot be overloaded|
>   
> nana/include/nana/paint/graphics.hpp|142|error:
>   with ‘unsigned int nana::paint::graphics::bidi_string(const nana::point&, const char_t*, std::size_t)’|

I only start study C++ 11 standart and Nana GUI library and cannot understand these bugs.

Comment: It seems that you have removed the NANA_UNICODE that is defined in config.hpp

Comment: I don't change files in library, just downloaded and unpacked in folder

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem.
To solve problem I look at how `nana` it self deal with this problem by compiling `nana` with `make VERBOSE=1`,
and take defines from it.

So to compiled example:

```
#include<nana/gui.hpp>

int main()
{
     using namespace nana;
     form fm;
     drawing{fm}.draw([](paint::graphics& graph){
         graph.string({10, 10}, L"Hello, world!", colors::red);
     });
     fm.events().click(API::exit);
     fm.show();
     exec();
}
```

from nana site(http://nanapro.org/en-us/) I use such command line:

```
g++ -DNANA_ENABLE_PNG -DNANA_LIBPNG -DNANA_LINUX -DNANA_UNICODE \
-DNANA_X11 -DPLATFORM_SPEC_HPP="<nana/detail/linux_X11/platform_spec.hpp>" \
-DSTD_CODECVT_NOT_SUPPORTED -std=c++11 -I nana/include/ \
test.cpp build/libnana.a -lX11 -lXft -lpthread -lpng
```